# Contact Form 7 - add custom function on email send

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Just playing around with `Wordpress / Contact Form 7`.
Is it possible to add custom javascript function on successful email send event?

Comment: maybe this is good for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Write this in additional settings at the bottom of the contact form configuration page:

```
on_sent_ok: "some js code here"
```

UPDATE:
You can use it to call functions like this:

```
on_sent_ok: "your_function();"
```

Or write some code (this one redirects to thank you page):

```
on_sent_ok: "document.location='/thank-you-page/';"
```

Comment: Can I put here JS functions etc.. ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it has some length limitations, I personally would just call my javascript function which is somewhere in separate js file.

Comment: What about form values? Is it possible to refer to form values after a successful submission?

Comment: @AamirShahzad Check your browser console for any javascript errors that might be preventing javascript execution.

Comment: Its now working i forgot adding <?php wp_head ?> hook... its working now like a charm :)

Comment: Can you use any contact form 7 tags here? I.e. [your-name] would be really useful for tracking users to analytics goals.

Comment: @digiout You can setup your form like this `[text* name id:your-name]` and then on `on_sent_ok` get it's value with jQuery like this `jQuery('#your-name').val()`.

Comment: If I am using  -> on_sent_ok: "your_function();" then where I have to define my function ?

Comment: @SunilGarg `your_function` needs to be defined anywhere on page or in javascript file that is included on the page. It's the same as any other javascript function, it just needs to be defined before it's called.

Comment: This solution prevents the display of the forms success-message. `.on` works much better (see below).

Comment: Problem - i'm getting error on any custom function except alert. Can't find variable: myfunc() 
any suggestion? thank

Comment: @alexela It's hard to say like this, you should probably open a new question with sample fiddle or page URL. You can reference this answer so people know what you are trying to do.

Comment: after spending couple hours, i found it. problem is that whole code must be inside " ", but there is another problem - "" making problem while using jquery (for example $('input[name='input']").func.) i playing with the chars finally let me do it. very very problematic plugin.

Answer (score 26):

Contact Form 7 emits a number of Javascript events that bubble up to the document object. In version 4.1 they can be found in contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js. If you're using jQuery you can access those events like this:

```
$(document).on('spam.wpcf7', function () {
    console.log('submit.wpcf7 was triggered!');
});

$(document).on('invalid.wpcf7', function () {
    console.log('invalid.wpcf7 was triggered!');
});

$(document).on('mailsent.wpcf7', function () {
    console.log('mailsent.wpcf7 was triggered!');
});


$(document).on('mailfailed.wpcf7', function () {
    console.log('mailfailed.wpcf7 was triggered!');
});
```

Comment: @likesalom does CF7 has something like .on('submit.wpcf7........i am asking because i am using this: `on_sent_ok:  "$('#hideform').hide();$('.wpcf7-form.sent p').hide();page_redirect();"` but it doesn't seem to work 100% of the time??

Comment: @alex You can listen for the submit event with jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: mailsent.wpcf7 and wpcf7:mailfailed have been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
   if($('.sent').length > 0){
       console.log('sent');
   }else{
       console.log('didnt sent');
   }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick note that on_sent_ok is deprecated.

Contact form 7 is now using event listeners, like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
      if ( '11875' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // if you want to identify the form
       // do something
      }
  }, true );
</script>
```

Then add this to the wp_footer action.

like this;

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp1568dd4_wpcf7_on_sent' );

function wp1568dd4_wpcf7_on_sent() { 
  // the script above
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I just try all solutions above before I read your post :)

Answer (score 2):

**Example 1:**

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://mysite.com/thanks/';"
```

**Example 2:**
In form script:

```
<div id="hidecform">
<p>You name<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>
...
</div>
```

Then at the bottom of the admin page under "Additional Settings" put the following:

```
on_sent_ok: "document.getElementById('hidecform').style.display = 'none';"
```