# jQuery - fire event only if form is valid - Wordpress - Contact Form 7

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

Using the [Contact Form 7](http://contactform7.com/) plugin on a Wordpress project.

Contact Form 7 does validation checks when the form is submitted.  If any validation rules are not met, it adds a class 'wpcf7-form invalid' to the form element.

When the form's submit button is clicked, I want to do cool jquery stuff, but *only* if the form is valid.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$('input#my-submit').click(function(event){    
   if ( !$(this).parent('form#myForm').hasClass('wpcf7-form invalid') ) {
       // do cool jquery stuff
   }
});
```

but of course, the `// do cool stuff` is firing even if the form has the 'invalid' class, because it's firing before the class has a chance to change.

Can I use the code above but delay the firing of the `if` statement, so Contact Form 7's validation rules can complete before my jQuery checks .hasClass('wpcf7-form invalid') ?

Thanks!

Comment: $(document).on('click','input#my-submit',function() ..... would probably work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact form 7 has a hook that you can add in the 'additional settings' box located at the bottom of the edit screen.

add this to the 'additional settings'

```
on_sent_ok: "// do cool jquery stuff;"
```

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333183/contact-form-7-add-custom-function-on-email-send) also answers it

Comment: THanks MArk!  Is there any way to hook this into a jquery script?  I ask because, in this case, I'd like to use the form in several places on the site, but only have the extra jquery events on certain pages.  If that's not possible, I can certainly create a separate form, but would rather not.

Comment: i'm not sure you can without `<script>`