# Wordpress + Contact Form 7 + The simplest modal window

Tags: jquery, wordpress, modal-dialog

I use [the simplest possible modal for jQuery](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal) on my Wordpress website.
And I want to show a message after a Contact Form 7 sent.
How can I open the modal window when the event happened?

```
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
    ...
}, false);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333183/contact-form-7-add-custom-function-on-email-send

Comment: Desicion:

`document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
 jQuery('#thanks').modal();
}, false);`